# Is it plausible that Noah's Dad knew Adam?

Tags: genesis, genealogy

I overheard in conversation this morning:

> My mate from college said that he drew a graph of the genealogy in Genesis 4 - and worked out that Noah's Dad probably knew the living Adam.

My question is: **Is it plausible that Noah's Dad knew Adam?**

Comment: My own graph indicates (from the genealogy in Genesis 5) that Lamech, the father of Noah, would have been contemporary with Adam (who dies at the age of 930 years) for 53 years.

Comment: Great - could you post your graph?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it is handwritten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Adam lived long enough to be able to see Lamech - Noah's father. :)

[image: Timeline from Adam to Noah]

[TimeLine from Adam to Flood](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=noah+geneolagy+timeline&t=lm&iar=images&iax=1&ia=images&iai=http%3A%2F%2Fcoatofmanycolors.net%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F08%2FAdam-to-Flood-2.png)

Answer (score 5):

According to the Bible, Noah's father was Lamech. For the purpose of this question, we assume that Adam, Lamech and Noah were actual, historical people, we get:

- Adam lived for 930 years([Genesis 5:5](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Genesis-Chapter-5/#5))
- Lamech was  lived for 777 years (Masoretic text, 653 years (Samaritan text) or 753 years (Septuagint text).
- Going by the Masoretic text, but in any case, Lamech can be considered to have been born about 874 years after creation.

These figures mean that Adam lived for another 56 years after Noah's father, Lamech, was born.

Answer (score 0):

The genealogy clearly shows Lamech and Adam were alive at the same time. What isn't clear is if they ever met face to face.  I know of no biblical reference to indicate either way. One could argue either position. About all that can be said is they lived in the same region. Interesting that Adam being the first man, his activities and where abouts are never mentioned again after creation.  Did he retire into obscurity with shame knowing he had sinned and caused the fall of mankind and separation from the Creator?  Put yourself in his sandals.

Comment: Welcome to BH.  As a biblical hermeneutics site, it would be helpful if you can provide any scriptural references to support your answer.

Comment: This is the place for substantial, documented answers - not further questions.